# What could be a good prediction model to use?

Tags: r, graph, statistics, regression, prediction

**Here is the data:**
Date is in Months, in my example there are 24(24 months or 2 years)

`l <- data.frame(date = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24))
k <- data.frame(cost = c(25,20,18,15,5,0,0,0,10,15,30,40,45,34,26,20,10,7,4,4,15,34,57,62))
m <- cbind(l,k)
ggplot(m, aes(m$date,m$cost)) + geom_line()`

**Graph Output:**
[image]

What is a good prediction model? I think I can use polynomial regression if I subset all the max values and subset all min values. see image below for better understanding. (Red for max, blue for min, lines were created using paint to explain a point)

[image]

Another way, I don't know what it is called, but I think they use it to predict the weather, 
Not sure what the formula to obtain the blue line below would look like. (Look at graph below for better understanding)

What would be an appropriate formula to get the blue fitted line to predict the points highlighted in red?? 
[image]

Comment: Looks like time series data.   If you have more data, then use one of the models that checks the trend/seasonality (check the `forecast` package).  Is it daily/monthly/yearly?

Comment: Never used the forecast package, I thought I could use a regression formula to predict this. but my data is big, its monthly. I want to predict cost of a stock from 1990-2019. this one stock I am working on has data similar to this example.

Comment: It is regression, with a prefix `auto`

Comment: Lets say I want to predict cost for month 27 and month 30, How would I get the values?     For example, in summary(lm()) I get the intercept values and other values which can help me calculate points

Comment: Regression is not the correct tool for this. You data is time series data (since it is monthly). You should look into autoregression. Try searching something like 'introduction to forecasting time series with R'. This should help you get started on your problem!

Comment: @BurlyPotatoMan please see my answer illustrating why I agree concerning regression.

Comment: Thanks, what do you do when there is: 2 dates for year 2014, 8 dates for year 2015, 12 dates for year 2016 and 5 dates for 2017. This shows that there is a lot of missing dates, how to build a time series model for such data? I have posted another question about it. Could you take a look thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of why regression is not good for prediction using this data. The model is "y = x * amplitude * sin(pi * (x - center) / width)^2 + offset" and while the regression appears to give an OK fit for *some* of the larger data set values of x, I also see the smaller values of x fit extremely poorly. This model does not fit the data very well at all of the data points or data regions, and seems to me useless for purpose of prediction because extrapolation outside of the data is so bad.

[image: bad_model]

Comment: Agreed.  Also, due to the time nature of the x values and the apparent seasonality, an autoregressive method involving seasonal decomposition and/or forecasting would prove much more fruitful than attempting to fit a polynomial or sine/cosine function using regression.